# BeautifulSoup scraping Bitcoin Price issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am still new to python, and especially BeautifulSoup. I've been reading up on this stuff for a few days and playing around with bunch of different codes and getting mix results. However, on [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/) page is the Bitcoin Price I would like to scrape. The price is located in: 
`<span class="text-large2" data-currency-value="">$16,569.40</span>`
Meaning that, I'd like to have my script print only that line where the value is. My current code prints the whole page and it doesn't look very nice, since it's printing a lot of data. Could anybody please help to improve my code?

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find('text-large2', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})

for row in soup.findAll('div'):
    for cell in row.findAll('tr'):
        print cell.text
```

And this is a snip of the output I get after running the code. It doesn't look very nice or readable.

```
#SourcePairVolume (24h)PriceVolume (%)Updated
1BitMEXBTC/USD$3,280,130,000$15930.0016.30%Recently
2BithumbBTC/KRW$2,200,380,000$17477.6010.94%Recently
3BitfinexBTC/USD$1,893,760,000$15677.009.41%Recently
4GDAXBTC/USD$1,057,230,000$16085.005.25%Recently
5bitFlyerBTC/JPY$636,896,000$17184.403.17%Recently
6CoinoneBTC/KRW$554,063,000$17803.502.75%Recently
7BitstampBTC/USD$385,450,000$15400.101.92%Recently
8GeminiBTC/USD$345,746,000$16151.001.72%Recently
9HitBTCBCH/BTC$305,554,000$15601.901.52%Recently
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find("div", {"class" : "col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left" 
}).find("span", {"class" : "text-large2"})

for i in div:
    print i
```

This prints 16051.20 for me.

Later Edit: and if you put the above code in a function and loop it it will constantly update. I get different values now.

Answer (score 0):

This works. But I think you use older version of BeautifulSoup, try `pip install bs4` in command prompt or PowerShell

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

value = soup.find('span', {'class': 'text-large2'})
print(''.join(value.stripped_strings))
```