# For loop in function, While true difficulty to understand

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I put this simple `Web Weather Scraping` script together, to check a temperature in a given location. The code works perfectly, even though, it may not be the best, or cleanest version. Still learning. But it is scraping: `<span _ngcontent-c19="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">67</span>` from [HERE](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/us/ca/san-diego/KCASANDI355?utm_source=HomeCard&utm_content=CurrentCondition&cm_ven=HomeCardCurrentCondition).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time

degree = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/weather/us/ca/san-diego/KCASANDI355'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
current_temp = soup.find("div", {"class" : "current-temp"}).find("span", {"class" : "wu-value wu-value-to"})

for i in current_temp:
    print('San Diego Feels Like ') + i + (degree + 'F')
```

The Output looks like this:

```
San Diego Feels Like 74°F
```

My goal here is to have a function that is looping, and based on the current temperature that is defined in `current_temp` variable to print for example if the temperature goes bellow 70F `It's too cold`, or if it goes above 80F `It is too hot`, etc. 
However I am having an issue to understand how to tell my code to execute, or in this case `print` these different tasks or methods you can say?. Excuse my English. There is definitely something wrong with the `While (True):` loop, but I can't get my head around it. Thanks for any help, and wish you all good Sunday.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time

degree = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/weather/us/ca/san-diego/KCASANDI355'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
current_temp = soup.find("div", {"class" : "current-temp"}).find("span", {"class" : "wu-value wu-value-to"})

def weather():
    while(True):
        for i in current_temp:
            print('San Diego Feels Like ') + i + (degree + 'F')
            #time.sleep(2)
        if (i <= 70) and (i >= 50):
            print('It\'s kinda cool')
            break
        elif i <= 50:
            print('It\'s cold af')
        elif (i >= 80) and (i <= 100):
            print('It\'s hot af')
            break
        else:
            print('You Dead')
            break
if __name__ == "__main__":
    weather()
```

Comment: I guess that `i` is a string but should be an integer when comparing it to another integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're collecting the whole `<span>` tag even tho you're only interested in the value presented, so to get the temperature value (and convert it to an actual integer) do:

```
current_temp = int(soup.find("div", {"class": "current-temp"}).find(
    "span", {"class": "wu-value wu-value-to"}).getText())
```

Second, your `current_temp` will never change once obtained, what you want instead is to periodically pick up the latest temperature value and then, based on its value, print whatever you want. Something like:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time

degree = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/weather/us/ca/san-diego/KCASANDI355'

def weather():
    while (True):
        # get the current temperature
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
        current_temp = int(soup.find("div", {"class": "current-temp"}).find(
            "span", {"class": "wu-value wu-value-to"}).getText())
        # now print it out and add our comment
        print(u"San Diego Feels Like: {}{}F".format(current_temp, degree))
        if current_temp > 100:
            print("You Dead")
        elif 100 >= current_temp > 80:
            print("It's hot af")
        elif 80 >= current_temp > 70:
            print("It's just right")
        elif 70 >= current_temp > 50:
            print("It's kinda cool")
        else:
            print("It's cold af")
        # finally, wait 5 minutes (300 seconds) before updating again
        time.sleep(300)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    weather()
```

Comment: Ohhhh I see now, that explains it. this looks even better without the for loop. Thanks for the help and time to explain this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: So I was also wondering if thats something I could use for this? [Here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724574/beautifulsoup-scraping-bitcoin-price-issue) is my Bitcoin scraping, Could I use the same loop to print for example,: Price is too high, or Price is too low, depending on how the value changes?

Comment: @uzdisral - I don't see why not, provided you extract the proper field from that bitcoin value tracking site.

Comment: Thats what I thought so too. And I've been trying it, here is the code https://pastebin.com/Mm6UenNW The first one gives me false positives and second one errors

Comment: @uzdisral - that's now going a bit out of this scope's question and certain;y cannot be tackled in within the comments. If you have a specific issue create a new question.