# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '196.41'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science, valueerror

I don't understand why it works with different scenarios, but not with this one.
Basically, some gentleman helped me out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745106/for-loop-in-function-while-true-difficulty-to-understand) with improving my code to scrape weather, which works perfectly. I then tried to do the same to scrape an ETH value which is in a span tag `<span class="text-large2" data-currency-value="">$196.01</span>`. So, I followed the same technique in the code, replaced the fields, and was hoping for it to work.

The code is here:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/'

def ltc():
    while (True):
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
        price_now = int(soup.find("div", {"class": "col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left"}).find(
        "span", {"class": "text-large2"}).getText())
        print(u"LTC price is: {}{}".format(price_now))
        # if less than 150
        if 150 > price_now:
            print('Price is Low')
        # if more than 200
        elif 200 < price_now:
            print('Price is high')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ltc()
```

The output looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 24, in <module>
    ltc()
  File "test2.py", line 13, in ltc
    "span", {"class": "text-large2"}).getText())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '196.01'
```

Then, I finally tried it this way; but from here I get false positives, but no errors. It prints whatever it wants

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/'

def liteCoin():
    while (True):
        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        value = soup.find('span', {'class': 'text-large2'})
        print(''.join(value.stripped_strings))
        if 150 > value:         # if less than 150
            print('Price is Low!')
        elif 200 < value:       # if more than 200
            print('Price is High')
        else:
            print('N/A')
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    liteCoin()
```

Would the problem be that the value of the ETH has a `$` sign inside the `span tag`? And, that way the program doesn't know what to do with string?

Comment: You should have a look at the basics of python e.g. [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/). **The title of your question basically tells you what the problem is**. Trust me, it will pay off to invest some time reading into the basics.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's simplify your sample program:

```
>>> int('196.01')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '196.01'
```

One cannot convert the string `'196.01'` to an integer number.

Try this:

```
>>> int(float('196.01'))
196
```

Moving from the simple back to the complex, we can do this:

```
#UNTESTED
price_now = int(float(soup.find("div", {"class": "col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left"}).find(
    "span", {"class": "text-large2"}).getText()))
```

Comment: Probably need to remove the currency sign too.

Comment: I thought about that, but the error that OP cut-and-pasted indicates otherwise: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '196.01'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand types in Python you are getting a float not an int and you need to cast the float to a string to print it. So there are two changes needed.

```
    price_now = float(soup.find("div", {"class": "col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-4 text-left"}).find("span", {"class": "text-large2"}).getText())
    print(u"LTC price is: {}".format(str(price_now)))
```

Outputs:

```
LTC price is: 195.44
LTC price is: 195.44
```

Comment: Oh sweet, now it actually prints what it needs to. Thank you